# PHP/jQuery clone - get variables from form and send email with php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am self-learner and I am currently building (trying to build) a simple form that has a row with 3 fields, and which dynamically adds another row with the same fields depending on how many items the customer wants. It will have a limit of 20 items. I am using this html layout for the fields that are going to be added dynamically:

```
<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        Part #: <input name="part'+i+'" type="text" id="part1" size="10" maxlength="15" />
        Description: <input name="description'+i+'" type="text" id="description1" size="30" maxlength="50" />
        Qty: <input name="quantity'+i+'" type="text" id="quantity1" size="5" maxlength="5" />
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" onclick="dupForm('input', '.clonedInput', 'btnAdd', 'btnDel');" value="add item" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" onclick="rmForm('input', '.clonedInput', 'btnAdd', 'btnDel');" value="remove item" />
    </div>
```

and this java script:

> function trimNums(stringToTrim)
>           {
>               return stringToTrim.replace(/\d+$/,"");
>           }

```
    function dupForm(divId, divClass, btnAdd, btnRm)
    {
    //alert(divId+'   '+divClass);
        var num     = $(divClass).length;
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);
        var i;

        var newElem = $('#' + divId + num).clone().attr('id', divId + newNum).fadeIn('slow');

        for (i=0; i < newElem.children().length; i++)
        {
            var attrId = trimNums(newElem.children(':eq('+i+')').attr('id'));
            var attrName = trimNums(newElem.children(':eq('+i+')').attr('name'));

            newElem.children(':eq('+i+')').attr('id', attrId + newNum).val('');
        }
        $('#' + divId + num).after(newElem);
        $('#' + btnRm).attr('disabled','');

        if (newNum == 20)
            $('#' + btnAdd).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }

    function rmForm(divId, divClass, btnAdd, btnRm)
    {
        var num = $(divClass).length;

        $('#' + divId + num).remove();
        $('#' + btnAdd).attr('disabled','');

        if (num-1 == 1)
            $('#' + btnRm).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    </script>
```

My question is: How can I get the variables into PHP so I can send this form to a specific email.

please note: I have more fields on the form and to gather the information in php I am using the following php script:

```
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$company_nameField = $_POST['company_name'];
$dateField = $_POST['date'];
$phoneField = $_POST['phone'];

$part1Field = $_POST['part1'];
$part2Field = $_POST['part2'];

$description1Field = $_POST['description1'];
$description2Field = $_POST['description2'];
```

and to post it on the email i am using this to test:

> ```
> $body = <<<EOD
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> Email: $email 
>   Company Name: $company_name 
>   Date: $date 
>   Phone: $phone
>   $part1 | $description1 | $quantity1 
>   EOD;

I know by gathering the variables of dynamic values, there needs to be a different code and I am stuck there. If someone can direct me to the right solution I will appreciate that very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arrays:

```
<div id="inputContainer">
    <div class="clonedInput">
        Part #: <input name="part[]" type="text" class="part" size="10" maxlength="15" />
        <button type="button" class="remove">Remove</button>
        <button type="button" class="clone">Clone</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="toolbar">
        <button type="button" class="add">Add new</button>
</div>
```

Using following code you can remove and clone individual inputs:

```
var limit = 20;
$('#inputContainer').on('click', '.clonedInput>.remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
    if ($(this).parent().parent().length < limit) {
        $('#toolbar>.add').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});

$('#toolbar').on('click', '.add', function(e) {
    var newElem = $('<div class="clonedInput">\
        Part #: <input name="part[]" type="text" class="part" size="10" maxlength="15" />\
        <button type="button" class="remove">Remove</button>\
        <button type="button" class="clone">Clone</button>\
    </div>');


    $('#inputContainer').append(newElem);
    if($('#inputContainer').length == limit) {
        $('#toolbar>.add').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});

$('#inputContainer').on('click', '.clonedInput>.clone', function(e) {
    var newElem = $(this).parent().clone().fadeIn('slow');

    $(this).parent().after(newElem);
    if ($(this).parent().parent().length == limit) {
        $('#toolbar>.add').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FwpUj/).

You can now access individual inputs fields in PHP using array keys:

```
echo $_POST['part'][0]; // first 'part' field

// print all fields
$mailData = '';
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['part']); $i++) {
    $mailData .= '#' . $_POST['part'][$i] . ' | ';
    $mailData .= $_POST['description'][$i] . ' | ';
    $mailData .= $_POST['quantity'][$i] . PHP_EOL;//or replace PHP_EOL for "<br>\n" it will work just fine

}

$body = <<<EOD
Email: $email
Company Name: $company_name
Date: $date
Phone: $phone
$mailData
EOD;


your_mail_function($body);
```

Comment: the java script of my question will make accessible the input fields in php? and can you give me an example of the php since thats where i need help to. i don't know much  of php

Comment: @JanTojnr how will the php script look like on the example given above?

Comment: Tojnr Thank you for you replies it means very much, can you check what i am trying to achieve. here is the site: http://www.spectrumcoatings.ca/forms/brandon/testForm.html would you be able to show me how can i create a working php script to send it to my email the values that can be added on each input?

Comment: If you change the form to use arrays (set name like this `name="part[]"`) you don't need to worry about all that stuff with id's and numbers and you can use that simple PHP code above for creating the mail body with products.

Comment: i did change the name=**part[]** and i just don't know how to let php know to print the valuse on the body of the email being sent. is there a guide where can direct me step by step? since i don't want to bother much of your kindest.

Comment: After submitting the form you will have all the parts in $_POST['part'] variable. It is de facto an array. Now you need to [iterate](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) through it and save the individual fields to variable (last code in my answer above). You can put this to the body as shown above and send the e-mail.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was what i didn't understood, my apology but it actually make sense now. Cheers!

Comment: It works perfectly, the code gathers the data and sends it by email successfully. what code can be added so on the email appears as list eg. part1 desc1 qty1, next line: part2 desc2 qty2...etc ?

Comment: I am appending the PHP_EOL constant which is a new line. If you are using HTML e-mails you can append '<br>'. Maybe you can try to replace the constant with "\r\n" but if you are using some advanced function this should be already done.

Comment: <code> $mailData .='Qty;' . $_POST['quantity'][$i] . PHP_EOL ("\r\n"); </code> this is what i did on last line. but it does not want to give me the list row.

Comment: Try `$mailData .='Qty;' . $_POST['quantity'][$i] . "\r\n"`. PHP_EOL isn’t fucction but constant.

Comment: stills not getting the list, its all in one linei used . "\r\n"; and also after i tried . PHP_EOL; but no success

Comment: Ok, i actually made it work by adding a breaker like this `. "<br>\n";` and it output the list as i wanted it. Thanks for your help @JanTojnar